# How to make webservice pass errors through NSURLConnection's connection:didFailWithError:?

Tags: ios, web-services, nsurlconnection

What does a web service need to do to cause `NSURLConnection's` delegate to receive the `connection:didFailWithError:` message?

For example:
iOS app passes a token to the web service, web service looks up the token, and then the web service needs to respond with an error saying "invalid token" or something of the like.

Currently, the data is received, and in "`connectionDidFinishLoading`:" is parsed for error messages. This means I'm error checking in two places, which I am trying to avoid.

I have both the iOS app and web service completely under my control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience (the three most dangerous words in programming), `-connection:didFailWithError:` is only called if the HTTP exchange failed. This is usually a network error or maybe an authentication error (I don't use authentication). If the HTTP message succeeds, no matter the response code, `-connectionDidFinishLoading:` is called.

My solution: call `-connection:didFailWithError:` when I detected an error. That way all my error handling code is in one place.

At the top of my `-connectionDidFinishLoading:`, I have:

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *result = [self parseResultWithData:self.connectionData error:&error];
if (!result) {
    [self connection:connection didFailWithError:error];
    return;
}
```

Comment: the first mention of `connectionDidFinishLoading` in your comment should be `-connection:didFailWithError:`, right?

Comment: The more I consider this, Jeffery, the more I think you are probably the most correct of any answer (although would like a definitive reference point). The delegate call back is *connection:*didFailWithError: not webService:didFailWithError:

Answer (score 1):

There are many conditions on which the delegate connection:didFailWithError: of NSUrlConnection may invoke.Here's a list of those [errors or constants](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003793-CH3g-SW40).I think an alertview would be better to show http errors in connection:didFailWithError:.

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection   didFailWithError: (NSError *)error 
{   
UIAlertView *errorAlert= [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: [error localizedDescription] message: [error localizedFailureReason] delegate:nil                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil];  
[errorAlert show];   
[errorAlert release];     
NSLog (@"Connection Failed"); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question is what do I need to do to cause the web service under my control trigger the didFailWithError: delegate callback.

Answer (score 0):

While not directly related to your question, I would encourage you to move to a more high level library. I can heartily recommend AFNetworking, it is production ready and I have used it in many projects. This will allow you to inspect the response code of each request in the failure block. This project also abstracts away a lot of the low level handling that you would otherwise be required to write for network communication; I'm speaking here about parsing and creating XML / JSON strings to communicate with a service.

To give you a more focused answer to your question, I would call the `cancel` method of your NSURLConnection once you have noticed an error in `connectionDidFinishLoading:`. This will automatically cancel the request and call the failure method of the delegate object.

The documentation for NSURLConnection is pretty dry, and the failure method of the delegate does not specifically document the failure cases. You may be able to find more information in the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html).

Comment: Interesting suggestion about calling `-cancel`. Documentation says: `After this method is called, the connection’s delegate no longer receives any messages for the connection.` which would lead me to believe that `-connection:didFailWithError:` isn't called, although practical application may turn up different results.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see the forrest for the trees.

I needed to step back from `connection:didFailWithError:` and look at a different delegate method `connection:didReceiveResponse:`!!

With the web service fully under my control, the endpoint could respond with a 500 status code, which gets picked up in `connection:didReceiveResponse`, and pass along some JSON further explaining the situation, which gets picked up and processed in `connection:didReceiveData:`.

The NSURLConnection delegate hangs onto a couple more bits of state throughout the process, but it has the best code smell I've found so far.

[Jeffery's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10402548/492847) was by far most correct: **the `connection:didFailWithError:` callback is only in relation to the network failing, any response from the web service means the connection didn't fail!**