# Why isn't connection didFailWithError not called?

Tags: ios, web-services, connection

I am sending a request to my server, and receiving a status code of 500

Why instead of calling `connectionDidFailWithError` the system is calling `connectionDidFinishLoading`

both methods have implementations in my class delegate

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make webservice pass errors through NSURLConnection's connection:didFailWithError:?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398448/how-to-make-webservice-pass-errors-through-nsurlconnections-connectiondidfailw)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP status code errors are not considered connection errors. If you get a 500, the HTTP connection did not encounter any error. It received a legitimate response: a 500 status code. `didFailWithError:` is for things like a "connection refused" error. You can find a comprehensive list of `NSURLErrorDomain` and `CFNetworkErrors` errors [here](http://nshipster.com/nserror/).

According to [this blog post](http://oleb.net/blog/2013/07/nsurlconnection-api-design/), `NSURLConnection` class was originally written for the first release of Safari in 2003 and the original goals for `NSURLConnection` still show in its API design:

> A web browser does not need to distinguish between HTTP status codes.
>   Regardless whether the response’s status code is 200, 404 or 500, the
>   browser can always get away with displaying the response body.
>   Consequently, NSURLConnection reports a 404 response as success. In
>   contrast, a web service client needs to handle a 4xx or 5xx response
>   as an error.